# How do I create a left-aligned, horizontal menu bar like the one in the image?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, controls

[Application whose style I would like to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMtYO.png)

I really love the overall design and style of this application and I know for sure that it was developed by C#. I would rather not violate any copyrights and disassemble the project, but rather create my own menu that is inspired by this one. **Also, I would like to use Winforms, if possible**.

How would I go about doing something like this?
Are there any notable open source controls that I could learn from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is about answering specific questions, watered down to one specific problem, that you have invested your time and research in. Please edit your post after you have tried to approach the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using wpf, you could use 2 frames:

### 1) for Buttons

StackPanel(vertical orientation) >> place the Buttons inside

### 2) for Page

place the page in the second frame
*Use a third frame for your app title.
Create a class with a property to keep track of which page to load into the 2nd frame. So when you click the "Main" button in 1st frame the required page is loaded into the 2nd frame.
Example:

```
public static class ActivePages
    {
        private static Uri mainFramePage;
        private static Uri headerFramePage;

        public static Uri MainFramePage
        {
            get { return mainFramePage; }
            set
            {
                mainFramePage = value;
                if (value == SignIn)
                {
                    HeaderFramePage = EmptyHeader;
                }
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MainFramePage"));            }
        }
        public static Uri HeaderFramePage
        {
            get { return headerFramePage; }
            set
            {
                headerFramePage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HeaderFramePage"));
            }
        }
        public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
        static ActivePages()
        {
            SignIn = new Uri("Pages/SignIn.xaml",UriKind.Relative);
        }
        private static void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
            {
                StaticPropertyChanged(null, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the xaml code for the frame

```html
<Frame x:Name="frmMain" Source="{Binding Path=(currentPage:ActivePages.MainFramePage),Mode=OneWay}"/>
```